# Screenshot tool that uses current state of web browser?

Tags: screen-capture, utilities

I'm looking for a screenshot tool that will snap the current page, *in its current state*. So if I've filled out a form, or changed the page from its default state in some way via DHTML, or I'm using AdBlock, that's what the screenshot looks like. SnagIt Pro on Windows works this way.

But the screen shot utilities that I've used on MacOS that do scrolling captures of full web pages all seem to send the URL of the desired page via Applescript and then snap the page using their own browser-like engine, which doesn't give me the state that I want.

Recently I've tried Skitch (Safari only), Littlesnapper (my current tool), and a few others that I can't remember any more. I don't mind paying a reasonable amount for a good tool, so I don't need it to be free... app store is always a plus. And I like having a screenshot-only library, the way Littlesnapper does it. Really, Littlesnapper would be perfect (odd interface behavior aside) if it just snapped the current page state.

Comment: Whoops I meant Snagit on Windows, not Snapz Pro

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? Screen shots show the state of filled out forms for me. http://imgur.com/w7XK9

Comment: He doesn't mean screenshot in the Mac sense, he's referring to a tool that saves a complete web page.

Answer (score 2):

### [SnagIt for Mac](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/features/mac/)

seems to do exactly what you want. I own the product. I just tested it on a web page in Safari with ad-blocking and with some text I typed into a field. It did a scrolling capture faithfully with all the ads blocked and the text still in the field.

Answer (score 2):

[LittleSnapper](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/littlesnapper/) looks to do exactly what you wish.

[image]

A free alternative might be [Skitch](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skitch/id425955336?mt=12). Both are on the App Store and you can demo LittleSnapper for free as well.

I use sketch more, so the rest of this pertains to that solution...
All snaps are stored in a Skitch folder in ~/Pictures and you don't have to pay to get what used to be the premium capture feature like capturing the entire browser window - even if it scrolls off the page.

You are correct that the "Safari Capture" re-renders the page, but it appears to inherit many of the cookies since it shows me still logged in here.

[image]

You could always snap the window (or frame the same size snapshot) multiple times and stitch them together if you need to make one larger capture of how your specific browser rendered a long or wide page. This stitching process requires another program as skitch only gets the snaps, you'll have to combine them elsewhere.

[image]